# Segmentation fault when running Terminal from Delphi project

Tags: macos, delphi, terminal, segmentation-fault, delphi-xe6

In my **Delphi** project I call some **terminal** commands to access a file and make some changes. When I run in **OS X** the terminal commands does not work properly. In the begging it said permission denied. I fixed that by using chmod 777. Then when I try to create a .txt file it says "**Segmentation fault**: 11"! And the command that tries to convert a image does not work at all. Anyway both of them work perfectly when i write them directly in terminal, without using delphi.

This are the lines I wrote to call this two terminal commands:

```
_system(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('./dcmj2pnm '+ pathdcm + ' ' + pathbmp + ' +oj') ));
_system(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('./dcmdump '+ pathdcm +' > '+pathtxt) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed finally to solve my problem! I am posting it just in case anyone will have the same issue. 
As I understood the system could not correctly convert the string (the command line for the terminal) into PAnsiChar. So I just converted it separately and then called the terminal. Here are my lines of code now.

```
comm := dir+'\dcmj2pnm '+ pathdcm + ' ' + pathbmp + ' +oj';
comm1:= dir +'\dcmdump  '+ pathdcm +' > '+pathtxt;

 co := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(comm));
 co1 := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(comm1));

 _system(co);
 _system(co1);
```